# Trailing slash lead to miss route parameter

Tags: laravel

**First of all, I have route in my routes/web.php file**
(I commented all other routes during long time experimented):

```
Route::get("someprefix/{slug}", [SomeController::class,'index'])->name("someprefix.page")->where('slug', 'foo|bar');
```

**My RouteServiceProvider looks pretty standard:**

```
..
public function map(): void
{
    ..
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    ..
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    ..
}
```

**Also I have controller with action:**

```
class SomeController extends WebControllerAbstract
{
    public function index($slug = null)
    {
        // Here we will also try to get slug directly from route
        $slugFromRequest = request()->route()->parameter('slug');

        dump($slug);
        dd($slugFromRequest);

        $view = $this->view("$slug.index");
        return $view;
    }
}
```

**Next, using artisan to build route cache:**

```
artisan.sh route:cache
```

**`Artisan.sh route:list` shows me proper list of routes. Everything all allright. But..**

When I request `/someprefix/foo` the result is `"foo""foo"`

When I request `/someprefix/foo/` the result is `"null""null"`

It looks like trailing slash lead to missing route parameter. Any ideas, what can be wrong?
 I really tired to fight with it..

Comment: Do you have another route? Like show route?

Comment: Yes I have many routes in my app but I disabled all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I created your example with clean Laravel 9 installation:

**web.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get("/tests/{slug}", [TestController::class,'show'])->name("someprefix.page")->where('slug', 'foo|bar');
```

**TestController@show**

```
public function show($slug = null)
{
    $slugFromRequest = request()->route()->parameter('slug');

    dump($slug);
    dd($slugFromRequest);

    return $slug;
}
```

**Test for it**

```
public function test_a_send_slug_as_parameter()
{
    $this->get("tests/foo/")->assertOk();
}
```

**Output:** for both tests/foo and tests/foo/

```
"foo"
^ "foo"
```